# How to end explorer.exe in Windows 8.1 (It restarts each time I do so)

Tags: c#, vb.net, explorer, taskkill

So I'm writing an app that needs to end explorer.exe before it installs. However, when using the following code Windows automatically restarts the process:

```
Dim proc() = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer.exe")
For Each item as Process in proc()
item.Kill()
Next
```

Due to this problem I found a way to kill explorer.exe using taskkill here's the code and it works perfectly fine:

```
Dim taskkill as New ProcessStartInfo
taskkill.FileName = "cmd.exe"
taskkill.Arguments = "/c taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe"
taskkill.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(taskkill)
```

But I don't want to depend on cmd.exe to do that task? Can somebody tell me how to do this using vb.net or c# code?

Thanks.

Comment: Whoa. Back a step first. How have you determined that you need to end explorer before it installs? Have you seen *any* other installer that kills explorer before installing? What makes you think that your app needs to?

Comment: Use an installer to install your application

Answer (score 2):

this may be not a good practice of posting others answers,so please forgive me,i just meant to guide you by providing a small light to your problem. this answer is actually from [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/511914/why-does-explorer-restart-automatically-when-i-kill-it-with-process-kill) provided by [t3hn00b](https://superuser.com/users/148160/t3hn00b)..All credits to him

to start with ,the windows (windows 7 and XP) use a registry key to automatically restart the explorer process.so to disable we have to programatically reset the value of that key,we can use the code.

```
        Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.Registry
        Dim ourkey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
        ourkey = key.LocalMachine
        ourkey = ourkey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", True)
        ourkey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 0)
        ' Kill the explorer by the way you've post and do your other work
        ourKey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 1)
```

or in C#

```
RegistryKey ourKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
ourKey = ourKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
ourKey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 0);
// Kill the explorer by the way you've post and do your other work
ourKey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 1)
```

Anyway i dont recommend changing windows default settings for a problem which have alternatives(using cmd.exe).

the code will have errors,forgive me for that too.just tried to give your problem a little start.try and check it,it is proved to work well in win7 and XP. you can see more details in the superuser link above.Hope it will help.Thanks to the [t3hn00b](https://superuser.com/users/148160/t3hn00b).

Answer (score 1):

In vb.net to kill explorer.exe you can use

```
    Try
        Dim Processes() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")
        For Each Process As Process In Processes
            Process.Kill()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

This will only work if you put the code in a **timer** and starting the timer when you would like to kill explorer.exe.

In c# try make sure you also **put it in a timer** and start it when you would like to kill explorer.exe

```
try {
    Process[] Processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
    foreach (Process Process in Processes) {
        Process.Kill();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: great solution!! Worked exelent for me